# How to handle control enable/disable option when running Background work with delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

On button_click event I have a query that will take lengthy time. So i run it on BackgroundWorker

```
     private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnGenerate.Enabled = false;
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                Data = DataLoader.GetData(Environment.UserName); // stored procedure execution 
                if (Data != null)
                {
                    GenerateExcel(Data);
                    GenerateSingleExcel(Data);
                } 
            };    
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                progressBar1.Visible = false;// ProgressBarStyle.Marquee 
                btnGenerate.Enabled = true;   
            };    
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

My problem is, I need to set

> btnGenerate.Enable=false;

at the button_click. and enable after the execution done.

I tried it inside `RunWorkerCompleted` but it's showing

> 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'btnGenerate' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that the events of `BackgroundWorker` are executed on the worker's thread, not the UI thread. But UI elements should only be accessed from the UI thread.

To solve it I suggest to use `async/await` instead of a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
// declare as async
private async void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnGenerate.Enabled = false;
    Data = await Task.Run(() => {
                var data = DataLoader.GetData(Environment.UserName); // stored procedure execution 
                if (data != null)
                {
                    GenerateExcel(Data);
                    GenerateSingleExcel(Data);
                }
                return data; // as suggested by Vlad, don't set Data on this thread
            });    

    // this is now executed back on the UI thread
    progressBar1.Visible = false;// ProgressBarStyle.Marquee 
    btnGenerate.Enabled = true;   
}
```

It would even be preferable if `DataLoader` provided an asynchronous `GetDataAsync`, so you wouldn't need the `Task.Run()`.

---

If `async` is not possible (for whatever reason), your `RunWorkerCompleted` handler should use `Invoke` or [`BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_BeginInvoke_System_Delegate_System_Object___):

```
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnRunWorkerCompleted;
//...
public void OnRunWorkerCompleted(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        // not on the UI thread - use (Begin-)Invoke
        BeginInvoke(new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(OnRunWorkerCompleted), s, args);
        return;
    }

    // now we're on the UI thread
    progressBar1.Visible = false;// ProgressBarStyle.Marquee 
    btnGenerate.Enabled = true;   
}
```

Comment: I think a slightly better idea would be `Data = await Task.Run(() => { var data = ...; ... return data; }`, in order to avoid multithreading issues on `Data` property.